# How to have a private maven dependency that is automatically included in a war?

Tags: maven, dependencies, war

I have the following situation:

```
project-A
project-B, depends on project-A
project-C, depends on project-B
war-project, depends on project-C
```

Then because of transitive dependencies, project-C has access to project-A.  I don't like this as it allows me to use stuff directly from project-A that project-B was intended to encapsulate (let's stay project-B is a DAO project, and project-A is Hibernate ... I don't want to be able to use Hibernate stuff in project-C).

However, the final war artifact must contain everything needed to run the application, meaning A, B and C.  How do I achieve this in a clean manner?

I'm basically looking for a new kind of scope that can be used in project-B's pom:

```
  <dependency>
      <artifact>project-A</artifact>
      <scope>not-transitive-but-include-in-war</scope>
      <!-- this dependency is needed internally only, but should not be exported as it is not needed to use this project -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <artifact>some-other-dependency</artifact>
      <!-- regular transitive dependency, that for example is used in the API -->
  </dependency>
```

I tried using exclusions in project-C (a half-assed solution, as it still requires knowledge of project-A), and also didn't work as project-A did not get included in the war

I also tried using provided / optional scopes.  Didn't work, they don't get included in the war.

I don't want to add dependencies only to the war project.  This requires me to have knowledge of project-A again.

### Why do I want this?

Because it allows me to make sure that certain projects don't accidently start using dependencies they should not be using.  Now it is way too easy to break layering because all dependencies are transitive (ie, I can use Hibernate at the Web level or one of the dozens of util projects like apache-commons, google-collections in every dependent project while we for example want to use only JDK stuff in certain projects).

Comment: did you consider using <scope>provided</scope> ?

Comment: ok, I read the question once again and got it.

Comment: I think the only way you could achieve this would be to create your own compiler plugin. While this custom plugin executes you can limit the dependencies available to be those that are directly defined in the current pom. If the project compiles then everything is okay, if not then you know it is relying on a transitive dependency and can fail the build.

Comment: Make `projectA` dependency `optional` in `projectB`'s pom and declare the `projectA` dependency explicitly in the `war-project`?

Comment: Nevermind, just read you didn't want to declare `project-A` in `war-project`'s POM. But you are probably over analyzing it; any project has every right to know about all its direct and indirect dependencies. That's what you gives you greater control over a project's dependencies, their versions and such. And FWIW, there's no way to do it with what we have, you may have to roll an implementation of your own.